# Using methods from 2nd-level extended class

Tags: ruby, inheritance, mixins, class-method

I'm trying to use methods from that is extended by the class that this class is extending from. An example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class A
  def foo
    "Foobar"
  end
end

class B
  extend A
end

class C
  extend B
end

B.foo #=> "Foobar"
C.foo #=> "Foobar"
```

I'm not sure if this type of functionality is available in Ruby. I know that this is possible by changing `extend` to `include` in `B`, but I'd like the methods available in `A` as class methods in `B` as well as `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extend` and `include` are for modules; you cannot, to my knowledge, use modules with `extend` and `include` (in fact Ruby will raise an error). Instead you should define A as a module and then `extend` B and C with A. See [John Nunemaker's RailsTips write-up](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) on `extend` and `include` to get a better handle on this design pattern.

Another option to do this is to have B and C inherit from A, like so:

```
class A
  def self.foo
    "Foobar"
  end
end
class B < A; end
class C < B; end
```

Comment: Wow, not sure why I didn't think of that before. That's what I originally tried, but I defined my method as an instance method, not a class method. Doh. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
  def self.foo
    "Foobar"
  end
end

class B < A
end

class C < B
end
```